# Do any of the standard Python packages implement the closed form cubic and quartic formulas?

Tags: python, performance, numpy, scipy, polynomial-math

There are exact (closed-form) solutions to polynomial equations of degree up to and including 4.  I.e. there's a quadratic formula, a cubic formula and even a quartic formula.

Do any of the standard python packages (or even some non-standard ones) implement these?  I can see that Numpy offers the ability to find polynomial roots (`numpy.polynomial.polynomial.polyroots`) but this routine appears to find the roots numerically via an eigenvalue method.

I'm *not* concerned about accuracy here (i.e. my issue with the Numpy routine is *not* that it will return floating point results when, perhaps, the answer is actually rational or integer in its real or imaginary parts).

I *am* concerned with speed.  Is it reasonable to expect that a well-implemented cubic or quartic formula would return faster than the eigenvalue methods implemented by Numpy?  I would have thought "yes".  But I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: You could implement them yourself: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CubicFormula.html

Comment: Yeah, I figured someone would say that.  I can't imagine I'm the first person to want this.  So wanted to give it a quick post to see if it was already there.  DRY etc.

Comment: I think the reason why you haven't come across closed-form solutions is that they are rather tricky to implement in a numerically stable way - [*"The closed-form solutions for degrees three (cubic polynomial) and four (quartic polynomial) are complicated and require much more care; consequently, numerical methods such as Bairstow's method may be easier to use."*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root-finding_algorithm#Finding_roots_of_polynomials) Of course, that doesn't mean it can't be done...

Comment: Try sympy, symbolic expressions for python, I think I remember reading the code for these formulas there.